# boost::unit_test::data operator ^ ?

Tags: boost

I was reading the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/test_org_reference/test_org_boost_test_dataset.html) and I came across this:

```
fibonacci_dataset() ^ bdata::make( { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 35, 56 } )
```

The ^ operator seems to concatenate two datasets together. Is there documentation on this, or do I have to source dive?

Comment: Looks like it's a zip, rather than concatenation. Docs are here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_case_generation/operations.html

Comment: Right! Thanks for that! (Why don't you post it as the answer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is actually a zip operation on a pair of [datasets](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_case_generation/datasets.html).

From the [documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_case_generation/operations.html#boost_test.tests_organization.test_cases.test_case_generation.operations.zips) of dataset operations:

> A zip, denoted `^` , is an operation on two datasets dsa and dsb of same
>   arity and same size, resulting in a dataset where the k-th sample of
>   dsa is paired with the corresponding k-th sample of dsb. The resulting
>   dataset samples order follows the left to right order against the
>   symbol ^.
>
> ```
> dsa = (a_1, a_2, ... a_i)
> dsb = (b_1, b_2, ... b_i)
> dsa ^ dsb = ( (a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2) ... (a_i, b_i) )
> ```

Hence, in the example you mention, the result is a sequence of pairs of calculated and expected Fibonacci values.